# The axiom of regularity and the real numbers

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, axioms

I'm having trouble understanding how there can be sufficiently many distinct elements for $\mathbb{R}$ to exist with its properties and yet still be a set.

(The `--verbose` explanation that follows includes all the bits that friends didn't understand immediately – just skip ahead once you got the idea of each section.)

### 1. sets are trees

Recall that sets are essentially just (weird) trees, and everything can be encoded as sets:
$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$
$\newcommand{\sO}{\emptyset}$
$\newcommand{\sSO}{\set{\sO}}$
$\newcommand{\sSSO}{\set{\sO,\sSO}}$
$\newcommand{\sSSSO}{\set{\sO,\sSO,\sSSO}}$
$\newcommand{\sSSSSO}{\set{\sO,\sSO,\sSSO,\sSSSO}}$

[image: example set]

This tree/set could represent $\set{\sO,\set{\sSSO},\sSSSSO}$ or $\set{\sO,\set{2},\set{0,1,2,3}}$ or $\set{\sO,\set{(0,0)}, 4}$ or … – doesn't really matter.  And the one on the left here…

[image: set with duplicate elements]

…is really the same set as the one on the right, because the branches 2, 4, and 6 from the root are actually the same element.  (They just *look* different because they are shown with "duplicate elements", which don't matter – look at the "triangle" at the end of the left set's rightmost branch:  It depicts $\set{\sO,\sO}$, which is actually just $\set{\sO}$.  You can keep dissecting stuff manually to identify the actual elements and get rid of the "ghosts"… but you don't need to:)

### 2. bounded size from bounded depth

There's an easier way to show that the example set above can't be that big:  Look at the "depth" / [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(set_theory)) of the tree – it limits the number of possible elements, and thereby the possible number of elements.  Here's all sets of depth at most $d$:

[image: all sets of rank 0 to 2]

(…and so on, giving at most [1, 2, 4, 16, 65536, 20[…*19725 other digits*…]36, …](https://oeis.org/A014221) elements.)

The example set in the previous image has depth three, which means that all its elements have depth at most two, so there are at most 4 different elements available for forming the set.  This means that the set on the left can't have the "claimed" size of 6, but can really contain at most 4 (distinct) elements. So we don't need to bother looking at the elements in detail to get an upper bound on the size, all we need to know is (a bound on) the depth.

### 3. the axiom of regularity / no infinite $\in$-chain

The [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) implies that no set has an infinite descending $\in$-chain (which is why [$\in$-induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction) works).  And so bounding the size of the set by the rank / maximum depth should work for all sets, right?  That would give an upper bound of $2\uparrow\uparrow d$ elements for any set.

### 4. the set of real numbers

We also know that [the real numbers are uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), i. e. the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be put into 1-to-1 correspondence with the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

### 5. the problem

But if there cannot be infinite $\in$-chains, that means the depth is bounded, which bounds the number of possible *distinct* elements, which… keeps things countable?  But then where are all those elements of $\mathbb{R}$ coming from?

What's the trick that makes this work without blowing up (i. e. no infinite $\in$-chain from which you could derive nonsense) while still preventing the collapse to countability?

Comment: Regularity does *not* say that "there can be no infinite $\in$ chains", just no infinite *descending* chains. More importantly, it is **not** true that "there are no infinite chains" implies "depth is bounded." You could have chains of arbitraty, though finite, depth. To claim that depth is bounded would be like claiming that because each natural number is finite, it follows that the size of a natural number is uniformly bounded by some $M$... which is clearly false.

Comment: (That is, it is *not* true that you can "bound the size of the set by the rank/maximum depth"; there may be no maximum depth, just like there is no maximum natural number, even though each of them is finite)

Comment: An infinite $\in$-chain isn't really "nonsense"--if you reject the axiom of regularity, it's perfectly consistent with all the other axioms to have such sets, and doesn't have any affect on the vast majority of mathematics.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, of course there's all the co-inductive stuff / the anti-foundation axiom / … that give nice different settings. But that _plus_ the axiom of regularity would explode. (Unless you manage to keep them sufficiently apart in some way.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A set does not have to have bounded depth!  Consider the set $S=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},\dots\}$.  Each individual path down the tree of this set is finite, but there are infinitely many branches that split up at the first level and each has a different length, so there can still be infinitely many elements and unbounded depth.

Now note that we can take not just this set $S$ but any subset of it.  Since $S$ is infinite, there are uncountably many different subsets of $S$.  If we take the set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of all subsets of $S$, we get an uncountable set.  This set still can be represented by a tree with no infinite branches, it just branches a lot in the first two levels!

Comment: Where you have "no infinite branches" near the end, do you mean "no infinite paths"? It seems like the root node and some of its direct children will still have an infinite number of children.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, the first level(s) will have _any_ number of children, but any particular path terminates.